# Webdriver is not locating the SharePoint dialog box?

Tags: java, selenium, sharepoint

[image]here i am switching to the frame. but its not switching its iframe[image]

```
List<WebElement> we = Testfactory.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@class]"));

         int iSize = we.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {

                we.get(0).click();

                Testfactory.driver.switchTo().frame(0);


            }
        boolean b;
        b = Testfactory.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@title='2013 MRA Choice']")).isEnabled();
        Assert.assertFalse(b);
        System.out.println("passs" +b);
```

Comment: can you share relevant html code?

Comment: @theGuy i have attached the screenshot of html code please have a look. can we connect on skype call? if you have possible to look into the issue.

Comment: are you getting any exception? are there any other iframes in the html code. As per code you are switching to iframe with index 0. You need to make sure if there are other iframes or not. Also [see this](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)

Comment: yes there is also other iframes. while i am looking manually its showing 9 iframes but while automating its getting display in list

Comment: List iframeSet= Testfactory.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
  
  int h = iframeSet.size();
  Testfactory.switchToIframe1(iframeSet, 2);

Comment: Its really not clear from the screenshot, can you share full html of the **page** in **Text** format (of course no sensitive information)